# How can you use foreground color when using Hue/Saturation (Colorize option)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I am using the adjustment layer Hue/Saturation and have the Colorize option checked. I guess it adds a layer over the entire image which then you can move the Hue bar left and right. What I am asking is how to use the foreground color for this? I want to color match this to a specific color. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the foreground color to the color you want **before** implementing the Hue/Saturation adjustment (as an adjustment layer or simply as an adjustment).

By default, the moment you click the `Colorize` option, the dialog box will default to the foreground color.

so...

1. Set foreground color
2. Create new Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer
3. Tick `Colorize`

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a kind of automatic color pipe from the foreground color adjustment dialog to your art layers, forget it. Or get some unknown piece of add-on software which does the trick.

I guess you actually want a possibility to copy a color for the colorization exactly from the selected foreground color indicator, from another image or to input it numerically. For it do not use Hue&Saturation adjustment layer. Insert instead of it a layer which has blending mode color and the layer is filled with the wanted color.

If you want to colorize only a single layer, you can do it non-destructively also by inserting Layer Style = Color Overlay. Use  in it's dialog blending mode Color for the same affect as by having a colorizing layer. You get a possibility to copy the color with a picker. Take it from the foreground color indicator.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the tip and did what you said, it worked and achieved the same effect. However the answer was that you need to set the foreground before you tick the colorize.